# Solving non standard differential equations

Tags: calculus

I have a non-ordinary differential equation here, $y'-y=-e^{2x}y^3$. I don't think this equation is separable. And it's not possible to find the integrating factor to solve. I think this is a bernoulli equation. So, how do I solve this? I have to substitute $\frac{1}{1-n}v'+p(x)v=q(x)$. How do I do that?

Comment: A terminology remark: "Ordinary differential equation" is a technical term meaning a differential equation for a function of one variable, so what you have is very much an ordinary differential equation (i.e., it's not "non-ordinary").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is $y(x)=0$ for all $x$. The other solutions are never zero, so to find them it's safe to divide by $y^3$ to get
$$
\frac{y'}{y^3}-\frac{1}{y^2} = -e^{2x}
.
$$
Now let $u(x)=1/y(x)^2$. Can you see what $u'(x)$ is, and how this gives you a linear ODE for $u(x)$?